# How to continue resizing after mouseup event in jQuery UI's resizable method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-resizable

Following problem: 
I have a resizable object and within that div there is a list with n items (can vary) - so i can't give the list a certain height. The problem is without giving the list a height the resizable icon is not at the correct position. So I tried to calculate the height of the list with javascript - now the icon is at the correct position but when I resize my div the maxHeight setting is ignored.

The other problem is that if I don't use a mouseup effect when the resizable-wrapper is left the resizing continues till you click with the left mouse button again. I created a mouseup event when leaving the wrapper but afterwards resizing is not possible anymore.

Here is a fiddle to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/5zdL9/3/

Is there a simple css or javascript solution for that problems?

**EDIT:**
Here is another approach - failed again: http://jsfiddle.net/5zdL9/5/

The Code:
**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="resizable">
        <div id="same_size_as_resizable"></div>
        <div id="another_div">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>1</li>

            </ul>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper{
    width: 90%;    
    background-color:#ccc;
}

#resizable{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}

#another_div{
    width:50px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}

#another_div ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float:left;

}

#same_size_as_resizable{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
$('#wrapper').css({
    "height": $(window).height() - 40
});    
$('#resizable').css({
    height: 50 + $('#another_div').height()
});    
$('#resizable').resizable({
   aspectRatio: 1,
   minWidth: 50,
   //maxWidth: 750,
   handles: 'se',                                
   containment: '#wrapper',
   autoHide: true,
   resize: function (e, ui) {
       $('#resizable').css({
           height: ui.size.height + $('#another_div').height()
       });
       $('#same_size_as_resizable').css({
           width: ui.size.width,
           height: ui.size.height
       });
       if (ui.size.height > $('#wrapper').height()){
           $(this).resizable('widget').trigger('mouseup');
       }
   }
});
```